# How to open multiple files without repeating the code

Tags: python, file, python-3.4

I am making a program that will open multiple files, they are all very similar. All contains a few one word lines in lowercase on Notepad. I do not want to repeat the code multiple times. Ideally I want to use a while loop to repeat the code but change what file it opens each repeat. Is there a way to do it? 
This is the current code:

```
File = open("Key Words\Audio.txt","r") #This will open the file called Audio.
Audio = [] #This creates the Audio list
Audio = File.read().splitlines() #This saves everything on each line of the  Audio file to a diffrent section of the Audio list.


File = open("Key Words\Calls.txt","r") #This will open the file called Calls.
Calls = [] #This creates the Calls list
Calls = File.read().splitlines() #This saves everything on each line of the Calls file to a diffrent section of the Calls list.


File = open("Key Words\Charging.txt","r") #This will open the file called Charging.
Charging = [] #This creates the Charging list
Charging = File.read().splitlines() #This saves everything on each line of the Charging file to a diffrent section of the Charging list.

File.close() #This closes the File(s).
```

Comment: Just make a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what functions are for:

```
def readfile(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        return f.read().splitlines()

audio = readfile('Key Words\Audio.txt')
calls = readfile('Key Words\Calls.txt')
charging = readfile('Key Words\Charging.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of the files you need to open:

```
files_to_open = [
    'file_1.txt',
    'file_2.txt'
]

calls_info = {}
```

Iterate over the list, and open and process:

```
for file_ in files_to_open:
    with open(file_) as f:
        calls_info[file_] = f.read().splitlines()
```

Here, I created a `calls_info` variable. What this will do is store everything in a dictionary. These hold keys and values - to access the value of a file, simply index it like so:

```
calls_info[file_path] # Make sure file_path is the right path you put in the list!
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in a function:

```
def openandread(filename):
    # No need to close the file if you use with:
    with open(filename,"r") as File:
        return_this = File.read().splitlines()
    return return_this
```

and then just call this function multiple times:

```
Audio = openandread("Key Words\Audio.txt")
Calls = openandread("Key Words\Calls.txt")
Charging = openandread("Key Words\Charging.txt")
```

or if you want to make it even shorter:

```
Audio, Calls, Charging = (openandread(i) for i in ["Key Words\Audio.txt", "Key Words\Calls.txt", "Key Words\Charging.txt"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Audio = []
Calls = []
Charging = []    
FILES_LISTS = (
  ( "Key Words\Audio.txt", Audio ),
  ( "Key Words\Calls.txt", Calls ),
  ( "Key Words\Charging.txt", Charging )
)
for file_name, list_var in FILES_LISTS:
  File = open( file_name, 'r' )
  list_var += File.read().splitlines()
  File.close()
```

Make sure to type `list_var +=` and not  `list_var =`.  This works because lists are mutable and because python works with references.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [unipath](https://github.com/mikeorr/Unipath)

```
# Install
$easy_install unipath

# In python
from unipath import Path

t1 = Path('Key Words\Audio.txt')
...
```